# How can we use UNION ALL with ORM queries in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Can anyone suggest on how to use UNION ALL in Rails 5. I specifically have two models and I want to use UNION for both of these models. Please suggest.

Comment: What have you done so far and what is the blockage? Could you post some codes?

Comment: I am just curious to know how does UNION all works in rails. I tried keeping the UNION ALL between the two queries but it gives errors.

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform `UNION ALL` in ActiveRecord(ORM) you need to put SQL query.

There is no existing method to perform `UNION ALL` in ActiveRecord